# How to get typescript file local cached path on Deno?

Tags: deno

when I use `import.meta.url` on local, it will be my local tpyescript file path, but if I run it remotely, like `deno run -A https://example.com/xx.ts`, this will output `https://example.com/xx.ts`, how can I get the actual local cached path like `/home/user/.deno/cache/xx/xxx.ts`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the path of a downloaded deno module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73596066/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-downloaded-deno-module)

Comment: Thanks, my need is more like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862831/how-to-package-other-resources-with-deno , I want to import a text file from deno, like rust `include_str!()`,  I don't want to use `fetch` from remote every time, cause it's an offline CLI tool.

Comment: Deno doesn't cache resources which don't participate in the module graph. You'll have to cache those yourself (or use an existing [community solution](https://github.com/denosaurs/cache)).

Comment: Thanks, if Deno doesn't cache the resource, I have to include the file string manually, cause it's an offline CLI tool, I don't want to  fetch any external resource.

Comment: You can use a cache solution during your build step so you don't have to do it "manually".

Comment: Thanks, now I build a `resource.gen.json` during build step, and import `resource.gen.json` on `main.ts`